# Searching a List of objects for a particular object in dart using "where"

Tags: dart

I would like to obtain an object from a List based on a specific search criteria of its member variable

this is the code I am using

```
class foo
{
  foo(this._a);
  int _a;
}

List<foo> lst = new List<foo>();

main()
{
  foo f = new foo(12);

  lst.add(f);
  List<foo> result = lst.where( (foo m) {
    return m._a == 12;
  });

  print(result[0]._a);
}
```

I am getting the error and not sure how to resolve this

Uncaught exception:

```
TypeError: Instance of 'WhereIterable<foo>': type 'WhereIterable<foo>' is not a subtype of type 'List<foo>'
```

I am trying to search for an object whose member variable `a == 12`. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `Iterable.where` method returns an iterable of *all* the members which satisfy your test, not just one, and it's a lazily computed iterable, not a list. You can use `lst.where(test).toList()` to create a list, but that's overkill if you only need the first element.

You can use `lst.firstWhere(test)` instead to only return the first element, or you can use `lst.where(test).first` to do effectively the same thing.
In either case, the code will throw if there is no element matched by the test.

To avoid throwing, you can use `var result = lst.firstWhere(test, orElse: () => null)` so you get `null` if there is no such element.

Another alternative is

```
foo result;
int index = lst.indexWhere(test); 
if (index >= 0) result = lst[index];
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple. `Iterable.where` returns an `Iterable`, not a `List`. AFAIK this is because `_WhereIterable` does its computations lazily.

If you *really* need to return a List, call `lst.where(...).toList()`.

Otherwise, you can set `result` to be an `Iterable<foo>`, instead of a `List<foo>`.

Answer (score 1):

or you can go crazy and do this:

```
bool checkIfProductNotFound(Map<String, Object> trendingProduct) {
bool isNotFound = this
    ._MyProductList
    .where((element) => element["id"] == trendingProduct["id"])
    .toList()
    .isEmpty;

return isNotFound ;
}
```